# Page breaking accounts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm developing a report for which I want to display multiple accounts/customers, with each one starting on a new page.

I have two datasets, with the main dataset showing the account information such as Product, Quantity, Price, Date and another dataset which has the address details of that account.

- The dataset containing the account information has a page break on the Account group.
- The dataset containing the address details are on another report which i've linked via a subreport.

On the first page, everything is display correctly. However, on subsequent pages, the subreports no longer show on the report (i.e. the address details).

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the sub-report does not show at all ? If that's the case, remove page breaks and see if its page break which is actually causing this (which I doubt). If this is the case, How are you inducing page breaks ? using expression or property ?

You may like to see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/841926a6-64ba-4387-b594-4087c8769aba/page-break-keeping-same-subreport-on-each-page) as well.

Comment: The page break is done by going to the properties of the row group and selecting the property Page Break options 'Between each instance of a group'. I removed the page break and indeed got the same result - subreport showing only on page 1.

The subreport has the parameter First(Fields!AccountNumber.Value,"dataset_name"). I think this is where the problem lies. 

I'm not sure if the way I'm going about it is correct, so feel free to suggest anything else. In case my original question wasn't clear enough, I'll provide an example.

Comment: The main dataset will return a list of account numbers ( ABC123, DEF123). The secondary dataset/subreport will display the address details for each account.

i.e. Page 1 - main dataset: ABC123, secondary dataset: ABC123 2 Smith St

Page 2 - main dataset: DEF123, secondary dataset: DEF123 5 Hill St.

Comment: I've managed to work it now. I've put both datasets in seperate reports, and then I have added them into the report as subreports. 

This solution has helped me http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d16068fc-cca7-43c3-8188-c383026f86c0/grouping-multiple-tables-tablix-with-different-datasets-ssrs-2008-r2

Thanks!

Comment: yes, page breaks on group should not keep sub-reports from showing. Also, what you have should work just fine but if you run into perf issues, you may like to get rid of sub-reports. Follow this sample in that case http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/creating-a-master-detail-report-in-ssrs-without-using-sub-report/